# Drawing described UML diagram with inheritance

Tags: uml, dia

I have some objects that I want to draw a UML diagram for. The first, A, is an interface, and second, B, is an abstract class which is derived from A.  The other class are C and D.  C and D are subclasses of B.

B has a list of E class objects.

F is a class which all operations are performed in it.  C and D class objects creates in the class according to polimorphism operations and then calls its methods according to users input.

Of course, there is a main class.  The main class only creates F class object.

I want to draw a UML class diagram.  What should the image be like? How can I draw F class ?

[The uml class diagram which is writen by my is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa3oY.png)

By the way I know that's the very basic image, I'll edit it after you response.

Comment: _I'll edit it after you response_ No. This is not an incremental tutorial place. State your question and do not change it upon any answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, this is what I think the UML diagram would look like.

For this statement "F is a class which all operations are performed in it. C and D class objects creates in the class according to polimorphism operations and then calls its methods according to users input."
It sounds like you would need to make a relationship between A and F because you are talking about polymorphism.  A should have methods.  B and C could have those same methods.  F doesn't need a relationship to B or C because the relationship to A implies there is a class implementing A but the concrete class name is irrelevant.

[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: That generally looks ok. But parts of the question (esp. which you cite) are more for reading the tea leaves. So you better should have asked for clarification first.

Comment: İf the main is that is there Composition ?

`public class main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Login login = new Login();


   

    }

}`

Comment: this is exactly what i saw in my inner vision! possibly add members to f in the form of a-objects named something along the lines of method1Command :)

Comment: With regards to the composition, to me it is mostly a style thing that I use because that was the convention used in class.  I have no strong feelings about whether it has to be there or the difference between white diamond and black diamond.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not add a comment. I would suggest two points:
- Maybe the aggregation could be changed in composition if Main class gets an attribute of type F, otherwise a dependency would modelize better the relation between Main and F.

- It would be more precise if a cardinality were defined on B side in the relation between B and E.

Hoppe this help to improve the good answer of ProgrammersBlock